# Appropriate categorical statement generalizing a fact about sheaf restriction

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, sheaf-theory

I am working through the definition of the restriction of a sheaf to a subspace, and proving that if $Z \subset X$, and $\mathscr{F}$ is a sheaf on $X$, then $(\mathscr{F}|_Z)_p = \mathscr{F}_p$ for any point $p \in Z$. From the definitions in Hartshorne, this reduces to proving that

$$\varinjlim_{V \ni p}\left(\varinjlim_{U \supset V} \mathscr{F}(U)\right) = \varinjlim_{U \ni p} \mathscr{F}(U).$$

I can work through the argument using the universal property of direct limits, since if $p \in U \subset V$, then the diagram of open sets containing $V$ is contained in the diagram of open sets containing $U$. My argument is the same as alluded to [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/938212/restriction-of-sheaf-via-inclusion-induces-isomorphism-on-stalks). I don't know much category theory though, and **I'm wondering whether there is a cleaner, more categorical way to see when taking two colimits can be reduced to taking one colimit?**

Comment: There is a Fubini-type theorem that (co)limits commute and equal the product (co)limits, when all such (co)limits exist

Comment: This sounds like what I'm looking for, thanks for sharing! Do you happen to have a reference for that result?

Comment: Leinster’s basic category theory or Riehl’s category theory in context. Freely available on the internet

Comment: Another way to see this (perhaps slightly less categorical) is that both of these inverse limits are restriction to a subset, and all you're doing is showing/using that restriction is a functor: the restriction along the composition $\{pt\}\to Z\to Y$ is equal to the composition of the restrictions along $\{pt\}\to Z$ and $Z\to Y$.